# How to play wav file from the resources

Tags: delphi

I need to play and loop a WAV audio track from resources.

I found an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960211/19160533

But when I paste it into my code, it says this:

[image]

My resources look like this (don't mind the name of the project):

[image]

The code I pasted into my project is:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlaySound(BG, 0, SND_RESOURCE or SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

And the whole thing looks like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Unit2, Unit3, Unit4, Unit5,
  Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure MediaPlayer1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlaySound(BG, 0, SND_RESOURCE or SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

Maybe I need to include some library or something else? I'm new to Delphi.

Comment: To use `PlaySound()` in Delphi, add the `Winapi.MMSystem` unit to your `uses` clause.  But, since there is already a `TMediaPlayer` in your project, why are you not using that instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks you for your answer very much! I do not know how to use TMediaPlayer with WAV file that is in resources. Is there a way do to so? If so, that would be much easier.

Comment: See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `PlaySound()` in Delphi, you simply need to add the `Winapi.MMSystem` unit to your `uses` clause.

But, since you also have a `TMediaPlayer` in your project, you could use that instead of `PlaySound()`, which would have the extra benefit of giving you more control over the playback (pausing/resuming, skipping, etc).

`TMediaPlayer` does not *natively* support playing WAV audio from a resource, but it can be done with a little extra coding.

Internally, `TMediaPlayer` uses [MCI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/mci) via the [`mciSendCommand()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757160(v=vs.85)) function. According to Microsoft ([HOWTO: Use MCI to Play AVI/WAVE Files from Memory](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/155360)), you can setup MCI to play WAV audio from memory (such as a resource) by installing a custom IO callback, and then specifying that callback when opening the player device. Fortunately, the callback is triggered by file extension, hence this approach is compatible with the `TMediaPlayer.FileName` property.

So, you should be able to write an IO callback function with a custom file extension (for example, `.RES` for resource), and have that callback load the WAV resource and read its data, and then you would set `MediaPlayer1.DeviceType` to `dtWaveAudio` and `MediaPlayer1.FileName` to a filename ending with the custom extension. The rest is handled by the OS for you, and you can then use `MediaPlayer1` to control the playback as needed.

For example (untested, might need some tweaking):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Unit2, Unit3, Unit4, Unit5,
  Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure MediaPlayer1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MediaPlayer1Notify(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.MMSystem;
  
{$R *.dfm}

function MAKEFOURCC(ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3: BYTE): FOURCC;
begin
  Result := DWORD(ch0) or (DWORD(ch1) shl 8) or (DWORD(ch2) shl 16) or (DWORD(ch3) shl 24); 
end;

function MyResourceIOProc(lpMMIOInfo: PMMIOInfo; uMessage: UINT; lParam1, lParam2: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Res: TResourceStream;

  function GetResourceStream: TResourceStream;
  begin
    Move(lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, Result, SizeOf(TResourceStream));
  end;

  procedure SetResourceStream(Stream: TResourceStream);
  begin
    Move(Stream, lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, SizeOf(TResourceStream));
  end;

begin
  case uMessage of
    MMIOM_OPEN: begin
      try
        Res := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'WAVE');
      except
        SetResourceStream(nil);
        Exit(MMIOM_CANNOTOPEN);
      end;
      SetResourceStream(Res);
      lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := 0;
      Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
    end;   
    MMIOM_CLOSE: begin
      Res := GetResourceStream;
      SetResourceStream(nil);
      Res.Free;
      Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
    end;   
    MMIOM_READ: begin
      Res := GetResourceStream;
      Move((PByte(Res.Memory) + lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset)^, Pointer(lParam1)^, lParam2);
      Inc(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset, lParam2);
      Exit(lParam2);
    end;
    MMIOM_SEEK: begin
      case lParam2 of
        SEEK_SET: begin
          lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := lParam1;
        end;
        SEEK_CUR: begin
          Inc(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset, lParam1);
        end;
        SEEK_END: begin
          Res := GetResourceStream;
          lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := Res.Size - 1 - lParam1;
        end;
      end;
      Exit(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset);
    end;
  else
    Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
  end;
end;

var
  ccRES: FOURCC;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ccRES := MAKEFOURCC(Ord('R'), Ord('E'), Ord('S'), Ord(' '));
  mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, TFNMMIOProc(MyResourceIOProc), MMIO_INSTALLPROC or MMIO_GLOBALPROC); 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, nil, MMIO_REMOVEPROC);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'BG.RES+';
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```