# Embed AVI as a resource file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, delphi-2010, avi, tmediaplayer

I have a `TForm` with a `TPanel` which is linked to the display properties of a `TMediaPlayer`. By selecting *Project -> Resources and Images* I was able to insert my video as a resource file, where

- filename = `abc.avi`
- type = `RCDATA`
- identifier = `Resource_1`

```delphi
unit uForm2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.ComCtrls, Mmsystem;
    
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses
  ShellAnimations;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  rs: TResourceStream;
  s : String;
  m : TMediaPlayer;
begin
  rs := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'Resource_1', RT_RCDATA);
  s  := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'abc.avi';
  fs := TFileStream.Create(s, fmCreate);
  rs.SaveToStream(fs);
  fs.Free;

  MediaPlayer1.Close;
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := s;
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
  MediaPlayer1.Display := Panel1;
end;
```

When the code is compiled, I get an error:

> There is no driver installed in the system

Actually, the "abc.avi" file is 1 MiB. If I use a 1 GiB AVI, I get an error:

> The file is being used by another process

How can I **play this AVI correctly as a Delphi resource**? The AVI in both cases has no sound. If I use a `TOpenDialog`, the video is played, but I don't want the user to select anything. The video must be embedded in the compiled executable.

______________ **Updated code and error messages** ______________

`TMediaPlayer` property:
MediaPlayer1.DeviceType = `dtAVIVideo`

Reported 4 errors:

> **1** [dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(56): E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeUInt' and 'string'

- Line: `Res := TResourceStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'RT_RCDATA');`

> **2** [dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(56): E2035 Not enough actual parameters

- Line: `Res := TResourceStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'RT_RCDATA');`

> **3** [dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(98): E2026 Constant expression expected

- Line: `ccRES: FOURCC = MAKEFOURCC(Ord('a'), Ord('v'), Ord('i'), Ord(' '));`

> **4** [dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(146): E2089 Invalid typecast

- Line: `mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, TFNMMIOProc(MyResourceIOProc), MMIO_INSTALLPROC or MMIO_GLOBALPROC);`

```delphi
unit uForm2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.ComCtrls, Mmsystem;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses ShellAnimations;

{$R *.dfm}

function MAKEFOURCC(ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3: BYTE): FOURCC;
begin
  Result := DWORD(ch0) or (DWORD(ch1) shl 8) or (DWORD(ch2) shl 16) or (DWORD(ch3) shl 24);
end;

function MyResourceIOProc(lpMMIOInfo: PMMIOInfo; uMessage: UINT; lParam1, lParam2: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Res: TResourceStream;

  function GetResourceStream: TResourceStream;
  begin
    Move(lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, Result, SizeOf(TResourceStream));
  end;

  procedure SetResourceStream(Stream: TResourceStream);
  begin
    Move(Stream, lpMMIOInfo.adwInfo, SizeOf(TResourceStream));
  end;

begin
  case uMessage of
    MMIOM_OPEN: begin
      try
        Res := TResourceStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'RT_RCDATA');
      except
        SetResourceStream(nil);
        Exit(MMIOERR_CANNOTOPEN);
      end;
      SetResourceStream(Res);
      lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := 0;
      Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
    end;
    MMIOM_CLOSE: begin
      Res := GetResourceStream;
      SetResourceStream(nil);
      Res.Free;
      Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
    end;
    MMIOM_READ: begin
      Res := GetResourceStream;
      Move((PByte(Res.Memory) + lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset)^, Pointer(lParam1)^, lParam2);
      Inc(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset, lParam2);
      Exit(lParam2);
    end;
    MMIOM_SEEK: begin
      case lParam2 of
        SEEK_SET: begin
          lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := lParam1;
        end;
        SEEK_CUR: begin
          Inc(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset, lParam1);
        end;
        SEEK_END: begin
          Res := GetResourceStream;
          lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset := Res.Size - 1 - lParam1;
        end;
      end;
      Exit(lpMMIOInfo.lDiskOffset);
    end;
  else
    Exit(MMSYSERR_NOERROR);
  end;
end;

const
  ccRES: FOURCC = MAKEFOURCC(Ord('a'), Ord('v'), Ord('i'), Ord(' '));


procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
 mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, TFNMMIOProc(MyResourceIOProc), MMIO_INSTALLPROC or MMIO_GLOBALPROC);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   mmioInstallIOProc(ccRES, nil, MMIO_REMOVEPROC);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'Resource_1.avi+';
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Display:=Panel1;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;

end.
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `TFileStream` as `TResourceStream` has its own `SaveToFile()` method. In any case, you should not save the `.avi` file in the same folder as your `.exe` file. Most apps are not installed in a user-writable location. Use a writable folder in the user's profile, such as `%TEMP%`, or `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYVIDEO)`/`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Videos)`, etc.

Comment: That being said, there is a way to use [`mmioInstallIOProc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmiscapi/nf-mmiscapi-mmioinstallioproc) to let `TMediaPlayer` play the AVI directly from the resource so you don't have to save it to a file at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. If I well understood your first comment, I will have to create an InnoSetup installer to write my `*.avi` file at the user `%TEMP%` and use the `TOpenDialog` to programatically read the video directly from that TEMP folder, right? As for your second comment, I would be grateful if you could possibly make a working wrapper showing how to implement that `mmioInstallIOProc()`  in my Delphi `Form2` to let the `TMediaPlayer` play the `*.avi` on the user machine directly from the resource.

Comment: Linking a 1GiB file as a resource isn't a great idea. Definitely going to be an issue if you have a 32 bit process, but a problem no matter what. Ship it as a separate file.

Comment: @jettald I would not recommend installing the AVI into `%TEMP%`. If the AVI is integral to your program, hace an installer put in the EXE's folder, or have the EXE extract it from resources into a subfolder for your program under `%APPDATA%`. And no, you don't need `TOpenDialog` since all these paths I've mentioned can be queried dynamically at runtime via Win32 APIs. Regarding `mmioInstallIOProc()` see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72326129/65863) about that (it was written for playing a WAV, but can be adapted for your AVI instead).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I followed your link and set `MediaPlayer1.DeviceType` to `dtAVIVideo` and altered `ccRES: FOURCC = MAKEFOURCC(Ord('a'), Ord('v'), Ord('i'), Ord(' '));` and altered  `MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'Resource_1.avi+';` and altered `Res := TResourceStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'RCDATA');`. There are errors when compiled: `Undeclared identifieer MMIOM_CANNOTOPEN` and also in line `Res := TResourceStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(PChar(lParam1), ''), 'RCDATA');` it says [dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(56): E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeUInt' and 'string'

Comment: @jettald `Res := TResourceStream.Create(..., 'RCDATA')` would need to be either `Res := TResourceStream.Create(..., RT_RCDATA)` or `Res := TResourceStream.Create(..., MakeIntResource(10))` instead. As for `MMIOM_CANNOTOPEN`, try `MMIOERR_CANNOTOPEN` (259) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `MMIOERR_CANNOTOPEN`is okay now, but neither `TResourceStream.Create(..., RT_RCDATA);` or `Res := TResourceStream.Create(..., MakeIntResource(10);` worked. I have now 5 errors: **1** _[dcc32 Error] uAbout.pas(56): E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeUInt' and 'string'_ **2**
_[dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(56): E2035 Not enough actual parameters_ **3**
_[dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(98): E2026 Constant expression expected_ **4**
_[dcc32 Error] uForm2.pas(143): E2089 Invalid typecast_ **5**
_[dcc32 Fatal Error] F2063 Could not compile used unit 'uForm2.pas'_

Comment: @jettald What does `uAbout.pas` have to do with this code? As for the other errors in `uForm2.pas`, since I can't see your updated code, I can't tell which statement the errors are being reported for. You have errors being reported on 3 different lines, which statements are those?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please, see updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245429/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-jetta-ld).